# Load XML with Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to load a XML in a simple page and show the contents of a group of tags, but I'm having some problems.

When I press the button to trigger `function`, nothing happens. I want to get an alert for every tag named "misil_aire_aire_otan" with it's value. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have right now:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>PracticeDOM</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function myfunction(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET","avionesPractica.xml",false);
    xhttp.send();
    var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

    var misil_aire_aire_otan = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("misil_aire_aire_otan");
    var textAPintar = "Éstos son los misiles aire de la otan : <br>";
    for (var i = 0; i < misil_aire_aire_otan.length; i++) {
     alert(misil_aire_aire_otan[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
    }
   }

  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <p id="paragraf_1"></p> 
  <br>
  <form name="formulari1">
   <button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <br><br>
   <table id="taulaAvions" border=1>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code fixed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>M04 - UF3 – NF2 – pràctica 3 - exercici 1</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myfunction(){

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            xhttp.open("GET","avionesPractica.xml",false);
            xhttp.send();

            var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

            console.log(xmlDoc);

            var misil_aire_aire_otan = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("misil_aire_aire_otan");
            var textAPintar = "Éstos son los misiles aire de la otan : <br><br>";
            for (var i = 0; i < misil_aire_aire_otan.length; i++) {
                textAPintar = textAPintar + misil_aire_aire_otan[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"<br>";
            }

            document.getElementById("paragraf_1").innerHTML = textAPintar;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="myfunction()">
    <p id="paragraf_1"></p> 
    <br>
    <form name="formulari1">

        <br><br>
        <table id="taulaAvions" border=1>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console, and have you tried logging xmlDoc to see what response you're getting back?

Comment: Also, just a quick note, you're going to have to declare your variables before you start assigning stuff to them. Just say `var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;`, for example

Comment: I'm not getting any type of error, and i have no idea how to log xmlDoc, i will research that a little, thank you.

Comment: Just write `console.log(xmlDoc);`, then press f12 to open the dev console and see what's there.

Comment: `avionesPractica.xml` is a local file. The browser will never allow you to do that. HTTP requests work on the same domain (ex. localhost). Your file needs to be served.

Comment: It seems the problem is with the onclick event, if i write on the body tag onLoad and call the function it works.

Comment: No it can't work. Because 1) you define `myfunction` but call `myFunction`, so it's undefined. And 2) I tried it, and I get the error : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///...avionesPractica.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` As I said, the browser won't let you access local files, you need a server.

Comment: It's strange, because now the code works (i will update the original post so you can see it).

Comment: @Green_Sam You probably want to remove the `console.log` after you verify that the XML is what you expected to get back!

Comment: I copied/pasted your new code in a `index.html` file on my desktop, dragged it in Chrome, and got an expected error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///...avionesPractica.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https` again. It is impossible that a browser allows javascript to silently load a file from the local filesystem. I don't understand how you can say it works and you get your XML data.

Comment: I have the xml document in the same folder that my html